# Hql Fetch: Condition on the right table

Tags: hibernate, hql, fetching-strategy

1st question on StackOverflow !

In HQL I try to execute the following query :

```
    FROM Device d
    LEFT JOIN FETCH d.listNotifications l
    WITH l.dateLastSending BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate"
    WHERE d.registerId=:registerId";
```

But getting following the error : "with-clause not allowed on fetched associations; use filters"

Filters looks a little bit complicated to me.

Is there any issue to set a condition on the right table ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `FETCH` clause.

(or try

```
FROM Device d
LEFT JOIN FETCH d.listNotifications l
WHERE (l.dateLastSending BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate) AND (d.registerId=:registerId)
```

)

Comment: when removing the fetch the error Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.site.project.model.Device

Comment: you can't `FETCH` and use `WITH` togheter. dyd you try second query?

Comment: Thank U Bellabax. I finally use @Filter as I had to deal with that with a single query.